# How does path_prefix and requirements in Rails routes work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Taking the 2 examples below - how do they work?

`map.resources :api_developers, :path_prefix => '-'`

`map.connect '-/:controller/:action/:id', :requirements => { :controller => /metrics|labs/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :path_prefix option lets you add additional parameters that will be prefixed to the recognized paths. For example, suppose each photo in your application belongs to a particular photographer. In that case, you might declare this route:

```
map.resources :photos, :path_prefix => '/photographers/:photographer_id'
```

Routes recognized by this entry would include:

```
/photographers/1/photos/2
/photographers/1/photos
```

So yours samples

first one

```
/-/api_developers/
/-/api_developers/1
/-/api_developers/1/edit
```

etc

second one

```
/-/metrics/:action/:id
/-/labs/:action/:id
```

since there is no requirements on `:action` and `:id` they can be any string like

```
/-/metrics/first_string/second_string
```